# Identifying environmental variables in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I have inherited a Rails app. My production.rb file has the following:

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    port:            587, 
    address:         "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    user_name:       ENV['NF_SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    password:        ENV['NF_SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    domain:          ENV['NF_SENDGRID_DOMAIN'],
    authentication:  :plain,
```

This app is not using the figaro gem, and I have logged in to the server (Ubuntu) and issued `printevn` for both the deployer and root users and don't see these variables. How can I uncover these from the production environment?

Comment: They might be passed in at start time (together with the starting command). How is the app started?

Comment: On a different though, you could simply edit the file you have shown the excerpt from and add e.g. `Rails.logger.warn ENV['NF_SENDGRID_USERNAME']`

Comment:  Not sure when you ask how the app is started? App is using Capistrano. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Where you added those `ENV` vars? Rails will not create them, but _read_ them if defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. These were configured in deploy folder on the server in /current/.rbenv-vars.